# Firebase: is child_removed called when parent is removed?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm managing a list of items with the following database structure:

```
root
  - mylist
    - item1: val1
    - item2: val2
    - ...
```

I attach `child_added` and `child_removed` event listeners to `mylist` and I (correctly) get notified when items are added or removed.

My question is: should I expect `child_removed` events for each item in the list in case `mylist` (i.e. the parent node) is removed?

The documentation is unclear, and in practice I witness both behaviors for two very similar lists. Shall I be notified (and there's something I do wrong for one of my lists), or is the other list notifying by chance?

In case `child_removed` notifications are not guaranteed, an option would be to listen to `child_removed` events on the `root` node too, and check if the `key` matches `'mylist'`.

But that implies adding `.read` access to the entire `root` tree for this user. And with a deeper hierarchy, how to know when any of the parents is removed?

Any other way to thoroughly watch the content of a list, including the deletion of the list itself?

Using firebase JS SDK version 3.4.1

Answer (score 2):

Looking more into this, I found the answer. For future reference:

**Yes**, `child_removed` will be called for each item, when itself or any of its ancestor is removed. See [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on).

The reason I did not see it in my case is because I called `off` on one of my listeners without enough parameters, resulting in an unsubscription of *all* my listeners.